# How to add edge weights from one graph to matching edges in a different graph in NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I have two different graphs in networkx, one graph has a total collection of edges. The other graph is a subset of the total edges. How would I take the weights from the total collection of edges graph and add them to matching edges in the new graph?

```
#total edge collection
G.edges(data = True)

OutEdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'weight': 10}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0}), (2, 5, {'weight': 0}), (2, 6, {'weight': 0}), 
(2, 1, {'weight': 0}), (3, 4, {'weight': 10}), (3, 7, {'weight': 0}), (3, 8, {'weight': 0}), (3, 2, {'weight': 0}), (4, 3, {'weight': 0}), (5, 2, {'weight': 0}), (6, 2, {'weight': 0}), 
(7, 3, {'weight': 0}), (8, 3, {'weight': 0})])
```

```
T = nx.Graph()
T.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 4), (3, 7)])
T.edges(data = True)

EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {}), (2, 3, {}), (2, 5, {}), (2, 6, {}), (3, 8, {}), (3, 4, {}), (3, 7, {})])
```

I would want the T EdgeDataView to look like

```
EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'weight':10}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0}), (2, 5, {'weight': 0}), (2, 6, {'weight': 0}),
 (3, 8, {'weight': 0}), (3, 4, {'weight': 10}), (3, 7, {'weight': 0})])
```

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the [networkx `Graph.edge_subgraph` function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph.html#networkx-graph-edge-subgraph).

For your example.
First creating the graph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2, {'weight': 10}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0}), (2, 5, {'weight': 0}), (2, 6, {'weight': 0}), 
(2, 1, {'weight': 0}), (3, 4, {'weight': 10}), (3, 7, {'weight': 0}), (3, 8, {'weight': 0}), (3, 2, {'weight': 0}), (4, 3, {'weight': 0}), (5, 2, {'weight': 0}), (6, 2, {'weight': 0}), 
(7, 3, {'weight': 0}), (8, 3, {'weight': 0})])
```

Next, choose the nodes you pretend to add to a new graph:

```
edge_set = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 4), (3, 7)]
```

Then, extract the edges from one graph to the other:

```
Di_T = G.edge_subgraph(edge_set)
```

Note that since `G` is directed `T` will also be directed, so:

```
T = Di_T.to_undirected()    # see NOTE in the end
```

#### Result

```
>>> T.edges(data = True)

EdgeDataView([ (1, 2, {'weight': 10}),
               (2, 3, {'weight': 0}),
               (2, 5, {'weight': 0}),
               (2, 6, {'weight': 0}),
               (3, 4, {'weight': 10}),
               (3, 7, {'weight': 0}),
               (3, 8, {'weight': 0})])
```

#### full code:

```
# example graph

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2, {'weight': 10}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0}), (2, 5, {'weight': 0}), (2, 6, {'weight': 0}), (2, 1, {'weight': 0}), (3, 4, {'weight': 10}), (3, 7, {'weight': 0}), (3, 8, {'weight': 0}), (3, 2, {'weight': 0}), (4, 3, {'weight': 0}), (5, 2, {'weight': 0}), (6, 2, {'weight': 0}), (7, 3, {'weight': 0}), (8, 3, {'weight': 0})])


# example edge set

edge_set = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 4), (3, 7)]


# solution

T = G.edge_subgraph(edge_set).to_undirected()
T.edges(data = True)
```

---

#### NOTE:

Usually a copy is made of `G.edge_subgraph(edge_set)`
(using `.copy`)
in order to obtain a new copy of the graph instead of
a reference of the original graph(see [the notes in the Docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.edge_subgraph.html?highlight=edge%20subgraph#networkx-digraph-edge-subgraph)).
However, `.to_undirected` already makes a deep copy of the graph
so there is no need for `.copy`, check [`G.edge_subgraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.edge_subgraph.html?highlight=edge%20subgraph#networkx-digraph-edge-subgraph) and
[`.to_undirected`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html#networkx-digraph-to-undirected) documentations for more info